# Exception in Installing Microsoft Visual C++ for Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, visual-c++, installation

I got the following exception when installing Microsoft Visual C++ for Python 2.7 from [this source](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266). Any suggestion?

> The cabinet file 'cab2.cab' required for this installation is corrupt and cannot be used. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the message your file is corrupted during the downloading process. The **solution** is Just *redownload your file from the specified source* and install it again. It works.